# opencart ssl протокол

Tags: opencart, ssl, https

есть сайт на opencart. перенастроил на https. и теперь у меня на каждой странице есть то самый значок "безопасно" с зеленым замочком.
на всех кроме одной странице. кроме главной. на главной используется so-home-slider и адрес картинок в слайдере начинается с http вместо https. 
Как могу исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможные варианты действий:

- Переназначьте фотки в админке на странице модуля слайдера уже под ssl.
- Константа `HTTP_SERVER` может присутствовать в коде шаблона модуля в цикле формирования структуры слайдера. Посмотрите файлы модуля. А именно `.tpl` файлы из `catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template/module/your_module.tpl`
- Скиньте кеши: `Дополнения > Менеджер дополнений > Сброс/Обновить (две кнопки в правом верхнем углу)`
- Поменяйте значения константы `HTTP_SERVER` в `admin/config.php` и `you_web_site_home_dir/config.php`, конкретно - замените http на https